# GF Pierogi - binding agent

Tags: gluten-free

I have the GF flour to make GF Pierogi however I was told to add xanthan gum? For the binding agent. How much xanthan should I use per batch of dough?

Comment: I don't use any (nor does my flour include any), but it depends on what kind of flours you're using and what your recipe/process is.

Answer (score 2):

If your GF flour does not already have xanthan included (check the label), or you are making your own GF flour, the suggestions I see online suggest that you add 1/4 tsp. xanthan per cup (120g) of "flour".